# Cannot compile iOS app with Firebase because of deprecated NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject

Tags: firebase, cocoapods, deprecated, nskeyedarchiver

I am updating a small application for iOS 12+. I updated the CocoaPod list to use the latest Firebase tools but I am unable to compile because `GoogleDataTransport` has a file that still references a deprecated method:

Line 129: `[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:self toFile:[GDTCORStorage archivePath]];`

It seems the pod is already up to date so I'm not sure how I'm supposed to get around this. Has anyone had the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Update to at least Xcode 10.1.

Recent versions of Firebase run into this issue with earlier versions of Xcode.

Comment: I was using Xcode 11 and iOS 13. I'd like to avoid going back to 10 if possible (so that I can compile against iOS 13)

Comment: Xcode 11 should be fine. What is the exact version of Xcode and GoogleDataTransport?

Comment: I was using the latest Xcode version (11.2.1 I think) and v3.2.0 of GoogleDataTransport. Neither seems to have a newer version available.

Comment: I suspect something special about your project configuration since that combination builds fine in our tests.  Might need a fully reproducible example here or at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues to help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution that worked for my case
Xcode 12.5 version

- clean derived data
- re-open project
- update the platform ios target to iOS 12 in a pod file
- run pod install
- re-launch your project

The reason for depricate errors is because firebase SDK set iOS 12 as the minimum target requirement, but in my pod file, I put iOS13.